# "Hew to" and "conform to/with" in AE

Tags: american-english, word-usage

Can "hew to" and "conform with/to" be used just about interchangeably for whatever register of AE, including the most formal prose?

> ...shall hew to the law and the recognized standards of legal construction.[source](http://www.ustaxcourt.gov/InOpHistoric/stallard.TCM.WPD.pdf)
>
> Rather than hew to the rules...[source](http://www.businessweek.com/news/2013-08-07/jumbo-shrimp-dot-random-order-dot-active-etfs)

Comment: Very uncommon usage to those who are not used to reading legal briefs!  But, from context, I would say yes. Not sure if there is a formal legal distinction, though.

Comment: 'hew to' is not that common and is a bit more grandiose sounding. So it is not 'interchangeable', they may have identical semantic denotations, but their contexts distinguish them.

Comment: I'm experiencing [blue car syndrome](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090411040609AAYFhNq) and I'm seeing hew to being used all over the place.  But, I'd still call it less common.

Comment: @DavidM nice to know that. What about "would you mind and...", "Would you be so kind and...", and "Would you be kind enough and...", have you lately caught any of these constructions over the place?

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Not even a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [*hew*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hew) is defined as *conform, adhere*, I'd say yes. And like many words in legalese, hew is a very old (1200s) word.